# How to set the default network interface for dhcp?

Tags: networking, dhcp

I'm running a headless Ubuntu server version 19, recently I slotted in a PCIe x1 card which then renamed my network interface from `enp4s0` to `enp5s0`.

Now whenever I start up the machine it cannot get a LAN ip address by dhcp unless I explicitly grab a new one with `dhclient -v enp5s0`.

Is there any way to make `enp5s0` automatically configure itself?

Edit: Added output from `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` as advised

```
network:
    ethernets:
        enp4s0:
            dhcp4: true
    version: 2
```

I see that it is still named enp4s0 in this, should I rename this myself, can someone advise?
Sorry I'm still a bit new with linux and still working my way around the system.

Comment: Hint, hint! Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Thank you, I have edited the question above with the results of the `cat` command.

Comment: I suggest that you edit the netplan file to change enp4s0 to enp5s0 and save and follow with `sudo netplan generate` and then: `sudo netplan apply` and then reboot. Did you get an IP address?

Comment: @chili555 I've changed the string `enp4s0` to `enp5s0` and reboot through ssh, I've successfully reconnected through ssh so that means it did the trick! Thanks for the help! How do I mark the answer? Do I answer my own question?

Comment: I'll convert my comment into an answer that you may accept. Glad it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you edit the netplan file to change *enp4s0* to *enp5s0* and save. Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate 
sudo netplan apply
```

and then reboot. Did you get an IP address? Check:

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

If you get ping returns, you are well and truly connected